# Cannot find resource named 'ViewModelLocator' exception

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, viewmodellocator

I am trying to use ViewModelLocator by declaring it as a resource in App.xaml. Its a very simple class as follows:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        public ShellViewModel ShellPage
        {
            get
            {
                return new ShellViewModel();
            }
        }
}
```

App.xaml file is as below:

```
<Application x:Class="SomeNamespace.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:SomeNamespace.ViewModels">
    <Application.Resources>
         <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

App.xaml.cs is as below:

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            var view = new ShellView();
            Current.MainWindow = view;
            Current.MainWindow.Show();            
        }
    }
```

ShellView.xaml is a below:

```
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Class="SomeNamespace.ShellView"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        Height="350" 
        Width="525" 
        ResizeMode="NoResize" 
        MinWidth="700" 
        MinHeight="700"
        DataContext="{Binding ShellPage, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}"
        >
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I can see the correct title in Visual Studio designer but when i run the app, get XamlParseException:
'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '11' and line position '9'.

The innerexception has **{"Cannot find resource named 'ViewModelLocator'. Resource names are case sensitive."}**

Am i missing something ?

Comment: +1 because the documentation is horrible for adding a View/ViewModel in MVVM-Light.

Comment: @ZachSmith Here I am just using my own simple ViewModelLocator class and nothing from MVVM light.

Comment: I realized. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5):

Try putting it inside a ResourceDictionary

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Edit:

I solved the problem by using the Startup event in the App, instead of overriding OnStartup.

```
<Application x:Class="TestWPF.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestWPF.ViewModels"
             Startup="App_Startup">
    <Application.Resources>
          <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Code

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var view = new ShellView();
        Current.MainWindow = view;
        Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: @mdm20 now i dont get the error but the window does not show up

Comment: Try deleting and re-creating app.xaml.  Remember to set build action to ApplicationDefinition

Answer (score 0):

At startup time you're loading the window, this is not a good practice in my opinion because the resources are not yet entirely resolved in both App in witch your Window depends. Even if you're seeing properties loading at design time this is not always a good argument, though design is following another logic to execute the code.
You have to let App and Windows load and then fill the context property in the Window's grid

Remove the resource XAML from App.xaml (it looks really out of the scope there) and do this instead :

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <wpfApplication1:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid   DataContext="{Binding ShellPage, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems i found a solution.The reason maybe the StartUrl in the `App.xaml`.

1.Remove the default StartUrl in the `App.xaml`.Such like this:

```
        <Application x:Class="BidingAccessories.App" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" d1p1:Ignorable="d"
                     xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
            <Application.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:BidingAccessories.ViewModel" />
                    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/BidingCommon;component/CommonStyleDictionary.xaml" />
                    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </Application.Resources>
        </Application>
        </Application.Resources>
        </Application>
```

2. override the OnstartUp event in `App.xaml.cs`

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            StartupUri = new Uri("MainWindow.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this part of code and run again. I am not sure about what's happening internally but that is what throwing the exception.

[image]